# How does RootLocusPlot handle TransferFunctionModel

Tags: plotting, functions, control-systems

I'd like to analyze the poles (denominator-roots) of a `TransferFunctionModel`, that was generated from a `NonLinearStateSpaceModel`.

However, I don't understand how `RootLocusPlot` handles the input of a `TransferFunctionModel` (or full transfer function) compared to when it is only passed the denominator of the transfer function.

Let's call the transfer function $G(s)= \frac{N(s)}{D(s)} =\frac{numerator}{denominator}$

I suppose `RootLocusPlot` builds a closed loop system and analyzes thus the closed transfer function $G^*(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)}$?

Would it be correct to only hand the denominator part of the `TransferFunctionModel` to `RootLocusPlot` in order to determine the poles of $G(s)$ as a function of a control parameter (i.e. `RootLocusPlot[tfm[[1, 2]], {F, 0, 20000}`)?

Example illustrating the different plots (1st plot: expected behavior poles of $G(s)$, 2nd & 3rd plot: closed loop?, 4th plot: seems correct only passing D(s) to `RootLocusPlot`, 5th: zeros of $1+G(s)$):
[image: plots of the sample code, showing different behavior of RootLocusPlot depending on input]

```
num = s^2 a1 + s a2 + a3;
denom = s^3 b1 + s^2 (b2 + F b3) + s F b4 + b5;

num/denom

constants = {a1 -> 3421.02, a2 -> 0.760227 F, a3 -> 21524.5, 
   b1 -> 5592, b2 -> 3421 , b3 -> 1.242, b4 -> 0.760 , b5 -> 21524};

(*build TransferFunctionModel*)

tfm = TransferFunctionModel[num/denom, s];
(*compute roots manually*)
Clear[roots]; 
roots[currF_] := 
 Root[denom /. constants /. F -> currF, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
Clear[roots2]; 
roots2[currF_] := 
 Root[1 + num/denom /. constants /. F -> currF, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}

(*plot different variants*)
ParametricPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ 
  Quiet[roots[F]], {F, 0, 20000}, PlotLabel -> "Goal: roots of D(s)"]
{RootLocusPlot[tfm /. constants, {F, 0, 20000}, PlotLabel -> tfm, 
  ImageSize -> 250]
 (*,RootLocusPlot[tfm[[1,1,1,1]]/tfm[[1,2]]/.constants,{F,0,20000},\
PlotLabel-> tfm[[1,1,1,1]]/tfm[[1,2]]]*)
 , 
 RootLocusPlot[num/denom /. constants, {F, 0, 20000}, 
  PlotLabel -> num/denom, ImageSize -> 250]
 (*,RootLocusPlot[tfm[[1,2]]/.constants,{F,0,20000},PlotLabel-> \
tfm[[1,2]]]*)
 , 
 RootLocusPlot[denom /. constants, {F, 0, 20000}, PlotLabel -> denom, 
  ImageSize -> 250]
 , ParametricPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Quiet[roots2[F]], {F, 0, 20000},
   PlotLabel -> "roots of 1 + num/denom"]

 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are understanding things correctly and I hope I am understanding your question correctly. The default is to assume a negative feedback but you may set this as an option using FeedbackType which takes values of "Positive", "Negative" or None. With none you are just looking at the poles of your G(s).

```
num = s^2 a1 + s a2 + a3;
denom = s^3 b1 + s^2 (b2 + F b3) + s F b4 + b5;
constants = {a1 -> 3421.02, a2 -> 0.760227 F, a3 -> 21524.5, 
   b1 -> 5592, b2 -> 3421, b3 -> 1.242, b4 -> 0.760, b5 -> 21524};
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[num/denom, s];

RootLocusPlot[tfm /. constants, {F, 0, 20000}, 
 FeedbackType -> "Negative", PlotLabel -> "FeedbackType->Negative"]
RootLocusPlot[tfm /. constants, {F, 0, 20000}, 
 FeedbackType -> "Positive", PlotLabel -> "FeedbackType->Positive", 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
RootLocusPlot[tfm /. constants, {F, 0, 20000}, FeedbackType -> None, 
 PlotLabel -> "FeedbackType->None"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, yes that helps. I was looking for the "None"-option.

I was expecting to see it more clearly documented under `RootLocusPlot` (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootLocusPlot.html).
There, they provide one example for the "None"-option, referring to it as "closed-loop", while they call the "Positive"-option an "open-loop". I'm not very familiar with the different control terminology, but wouldn't it be exactly the other way round?

The same terminology is used under:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeedbackType.html

Comment: @Fabian Strange, I would have said "none" is open-loop and "positive"/"negative" are the closed loop variants, too. Also `RootLocusPlot[
 SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[tfm, "Negative"] /. constants, {F, 0, 
  20000},FeedbackType->None, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]` should give the same as `RootLocusPlot[tfm /. constants, {F, 0, 20000}, 
 FeedbackType -> "Negative"]`. So that's my understanding of closed loop/open loop.